# Let $U\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be open and connected and $f:U\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function. Show that $f$ is constant given...

Tags: real-analysis

Sorry about the poor title, but I hit a character limit wall. I will put the full question below.

Let $U\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be open and connected and $f:U\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function. Suppose there exists constants $C>0$ and $a>1$ such that $|f(x)-f(y)|\leq C|x-y|^a$ for all $x,y\in U$. Show $f$ is constant.

I received a hint to look at the differentiability of $f$ so this is what I did.$$\lim_{|h|\rightarrow0}\frac{|f(x+h)-f(x)-B\cdot h|}{|h|}$$
$$\leq\lim_{|h|\rightarrow0}\frac{|f(a+h)-f(a)|+|-B\cdot h|}{|h|}$$
$$\leq\lim_{|h|\rightarrow0}\frac{C|h|^a+|-B\cdot h|}{|h|}$$
$$=\lim_{|h|\rightarrow0}\frac{C|h|^a+|-B|\cdot |h|}{|h|}$$
$$=\lim_{|h|\rightarrow0}C|h|^{a-1}+|-B|$$

Since $a>1$ then $a-1>0$. Therefore, this limit evaluates to $0$ iff $B=0$. Then $B=0$ in the first limit, or else that limit would not necessarily evaluate to $0$. Therefore $Df=0$ for all $x$. Therefore, $f$ is constant.

I was wondering if this was a valid proof or not. Please help me out if you can.

The next step in this question is whether or not it is necessary for $U$ to be connected. I don't know how to approach this question, since it seems I didn't use connectedness in the above proof. Maybe I've missed something?

Thanks.

Comment: Just for the notation: $f(x)$, $f(y)$ are real numbers, but $x,y$ are in $\mathbb{R}^n$. So, use $||x-y||$, not $|x-y|$.

Comment: @IoannisSouldatos: Both uses of the notation are common.

Comment: @Clayton I know, but it is misleading. For instance $h$ is an element of $\mathbb{R}^n$. What is $B\cdot h$? It is not a product of real numbers.

Comment: @IoannisSouldatos: It is the dot product, per the definition of derivative in $\Bbb R^n$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You nicely show that $Df=0$. From this you can conclude that $f$ is *locally* constant. If $U$ fails to be connected, we might have different constants per connected component.

Comment: So I didn't actually manage to show that $f$ was constant, only that it was constant on each connected component. But since $U$ is connected, there is only one such connected component. Therefore $f$ is constant. So I now see why $U$ must be connected or, as you say, we might have different constants per connected component.

Answer (score 1):

FYI, here's another approach: Suppose the line segment $[p,q]\subset U.$ For $m\in \mathbb N,$ let $x_k = p+ (k/m)(q-p), k = 0,\dots , m.$ Note that $|x_k-x_{k-1}| = |q-p|/m.$ Now

$$f(q)-f(p) = \sum_{k=1}^{m }(f(x_k)-f(x_{k-1})) \implies |f(q)-f(p)| \le\sum_{k=1}^{m }|f(x_k)-f(x_{k-1})|.  $$

On the right, there are $m$ summands, each no more than $C(|q-p|/m)^a.$ It follows that

$$|f(q)-f(p)|\le m\cdot C(|q-p|/m)^a = C|q-p|^am^{1-a}.$$

Because $a>1,$ the last expression $\to 0$ as $m\to \infty.$ Hence $|f(q)-f(p)|=0.$ This shows $f$ is locally constant, and since $U$ is connected, $f$ is constant in $U.$